# Keosd connection error

Tags: cleos

I recently migrated over to EOS v1.0.1 and started `nodeos` as per usual, specifying my `--config-dir` which contains my previous `config.ini`.

```
nodeos -e -p eosio --config-dir ~/eosio-wallet
```

`Nodeos` starts producing blocks normally, but when I try to connect with `cleos`, I get the following output and error;

```
"/usr/local/bin/keosd" launched
Unable to connect to keosd, if keosd is running please kill the process and try again.
```

My `config.ini`, without comments, is as follows;

```
http-server-address = 127.0.0.1:8888
access-control-allow-origin = *
access-control-allow-credentials = false
wallet-dir = "."
unlock-timeout = 3600
producer-name = eosio
enable-stale-production = true
plugin = eosio::http_plugin
plugin = eosio::chain_api_plugin
plugin = eosio::history_api_plugin
plugin = eosio::wallet_api_plugin
plugin = eosio::producer_plugin
```

How can I restart or kill keosd? I've tried `killall keosd` and `pgrep keosd`, but the process doesn't seem to be running. Calling `keosd` itself outputs;
422033ms thread-0   main.cpp:52                   main                 ]

```
~/contracts/eos/libraries/appbase/application.cpp(304): Throw in function appbase::abstract_plugin &appbase::application::get_plugin(const string &) const
Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::runtime_error> >
std::exception::what: unable to find plugin: eosio::chain_api_plugin
```

Answer (score 3):

You can provide both `nodeos` and `keosd` urls with
`cleos -u http://localhost:8888 --wallet-url http://localhost:8889 your commands`

- `-u` sets `nodeos` url
- `--wallet-url` is for `keosd`

To change default `keosd` port (8889 here), set `http-server-address` value in wallet config (`~/eosio-wallet/config.ini`)

Comment: +1 As this worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 with an EOS early September master build

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same issue.

you don't use wallet's config.ini

that config file may be keosd's default config file.

And don't use eosio::chain_plugin_api in wallet's config

using nodeos default config file

> config.ini can be found at the following locations:
>
> Mac OS: ~/Library/Application Support/eosio/nodeos/config
>
> Linux: ~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config

ref. https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/configuration-file

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that you start nodeos and keosd with the same port.
Let's specify other port for keosd.

The following is an example for you:
./keosd --http-server-address=localhost:8899

Comment: This didn't work, and returned the same error. I tried with the port you suggested `8899` and with the actual port nodeos is listening on `8888`.

Comment: plz show your command that hits the error.

Comment: `keosd --http-server-address=localhost:8899`
     
`1478549ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:285           plugin_initialize    ] configured http to listen on localhost:8899
1478549ms thread-0   main.cpp:52                   main                 ] ~/contracts/eos/libraries/appbase/application.cpp(304): Throw in function appbase::abstract_plugin &appbase::application::get_plugin(const string &) const
Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::runtime_error> >
std::exception::what: unable to find plugin: eosio::chain_api_plugin`

Comment: It seems that when start nodeos you missed plug-in eosio::chain_api_plugin. Try to restart EOSIO and add plug-in: --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin

Comment: Still the same error... `plugin = eosio::chain_api_plugin` is in my `config.ini`, but I added it as a flag `--plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin` as well.

Comment: Running `cleos wallet list` gives the following output; `"/usr/local/bin/keosd" launched`
`Unable to connect to keosd, if keosd is running please kill the process and try again.`

Comment: try this: cleos -u http://localhost:8899 wallet list

Comment: Same output; `"/usr/local/bin/keosd" launched
Unable to connect to keosd, if keosd is running please kill the process and try again.` I've now raised the issue with EOS on GitHub as well.

Answer (score 0):

From your config, it looks like you're binding `keosd` to an IP address `127.0.0.1:8888` (EOS default as well) and trying access that using a hostname `localhost`. Try accessing using the IP `127.0.0.1` instead. For example, start the node:

```
$ nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin \
--plugin eosio::history_api_plugin
```

In a separate terminal session, run:

```
$ cleos -u http://127.0.0.1:8888 --wallet-url http://127.0.0.1:8889 wallet create

"/usr/local/bin/keosd" launched
Creating wallet: default
Save password to use in the future to unlock this wallet.
Without password imported keys will not be retrievable.
"PW5HtJaAwPQt65dF6mkanXFDC4q4gQh2rdD6wbnv35QPwWiGKJTAR"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps to kill `keosd`

Find PID of the running keosd process

```
ps -ef | grep keosd
```

Kill it

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

//replace `<pid>` with value returned by the first command

Run keosd in a specified port(8900)

```
keosd --http-server-address=127.0.0.1:8900
```